# how to pass a multiple dynamic value from single column using sql procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

My sample table:

```
item   | id
-------+-----
mobile | 1
car    | 2
pen    | 3
```

I am trying to create a procedure which passes the multiple dynamic value from single column (`item`), for example: mobile,car etc.

Code:

```
create procedure g_items
    @im varchar(25)
as
    select * 
    from item 
    where item in (@im)
go

exec g_items @im ='pen','mobile'
```

Error:

> Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'.  After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Two things -

1. When you write ' *exec g_items @im ='pen','mobile'* ',  you are trying to pass two parameters to the stored procedure, where the second parameter is not in the form @name = @value pair (like the first @im = 'pen'), hence the error.
2. I understand that you want to pass multiple values (list of values) to the stored procedure in a single parameter, so that you can query the table with in clause containing all the values from the list passed to stored procedure. For this i would suggest you change stored procedure as below -

---

```
create procedure g_items @im varchar(25)
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = replace(@im,',',''',''')
set @sql = 'select * from item where item in ('''+@sql+''')'
exec sp_executesql @sql
go
```

---

The above code will execute dynamically generated SQL query. First we have to surround all the commas with single quotes, that's what the replace statement is doing, then we have to enclose the entire list in round braces along with actual SQL statement and then we finally execute this dynamic SQL statement to get desired output. To execute the procedure please use below code

---

```
exec g_items @im ='pen,mobile'
```

Comment: while running this i'm getting same error.can you tell me how to execute this procedure?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that. You can execute it using exec g_items @im ='pen,mobile' . I have also updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also you can check `User defined table` type if you want to pass multiple values